# Material Design grid doesn't work well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, material-design

I have a problem with material grid on medium screen. The same code works well with bootstrap:

**In material case:**

http://codepen.io/lampt2509/pen/egdZxp

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.mdl-cell {
  height: 100px;
}

.mdl-cell:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.mdl-cell:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

[image: Material Design]

**With bootstrap:**

http://codepen.io/lampt2509/pen/VPKaRr

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.row > div {
  height: 100px;
}

.row > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.row > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

[image: Bootstrap]

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: can u post full code or link to codepen or similar

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated my post.

Comment: i added `width:100%;` and it worked fine

Comment: You set width = 100% for the first "mdl-cell" ? But in that case, in the large screen, the first cell will always take 12 columns... not 4 columns and leave 8 columns for the next cell.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice the following line in the material's doc. It is different from bootstrap.

> A grid has 12 columns in the desktop screen size, 8 in the tablet size, and 4 in the phone size

So the cells' classes must become:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--3-col-tablet mdl-cell--1-col-phone"></div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col mdl-cell--5-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-phone"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/lampt2509/pen/BpLzNb

And it works.